# How to render fusioncharts with node express using jade template?

Tags: express, pug, fusioncharts

Trying out fusioncharts.js, so far I've achieved to display the chart/gauge with plain HTML and javascript JSON. Then trying to translate it with jade-lang, and using middleware the graph doesn't render.I m guessing problem may be with translating HTML code to jade, needing additional dependencies to be installed or not rendering at all or at the wrong time. What is the exact way to get fusioncharts working with jade ?